# Javascript - Pausing mp3 file with second click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a group of play buttons and as soon as you click one, a song plays. However I have not succeeded in pausing the song and then playing another song when I click another button.

Javascript

```
 function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    if(!audie.src) 
       audie.src = audioFile;
    if(audie.paused == false) {
        audie.pause();
    } else {
       audie.play();
    }
 }
```

HTML

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="57" height="50" onclick="StartOrStop('RWY.mp3')">

<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="57" height="50" onclick="StartOrStop('WDC.mp3')">
```

Any suggestions on how I may fix it?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the HTML around `alt="Play Button width="57"`, is that just a typo when copying onto Stack Overflow?

Comment: yes its just a typo definitely nothing to do with that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to give a try [Buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/).This js library helps to do common thing easily.

Answer (score 0):

**you need to load the other audio file after src is changed**

```
    function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    if(!audie.src) 
       audie.src = audioFile;
       audie.load();
    if(audie.paused == false) {
        audie.pause();
    } else {
       audie.play();
    }
 }
```